# Use parameterized test returns Method should have no parameters

Tags: java, junit, parameterized-tests

I have a problem, I would like to pass the test method to send a request using the GET method and POST. I used parameterization, but I get information java.lang.Exception: Method simpleMessage should have no parameters

```
  @Test
    @ParameterizedTest
    @ValueSource(strings = {"true", "false"})
    public void simpleMessage (boolean isPost) {
        verifyIdOdpEqual(isPost,1243, "message");
    }
```

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do, but the test is like a void function you first run the function with the annotation and inside the function you tell it to run other functions like "simpleMessage (boolean isPost) " function. 

Basically create @Test testPostFunction(){ Add starting condition. do something in simpleMessage(boolean) function and assert if the simpleMessage result worked or failed. 

the name "verifyIdOdpEqual" does not tell me quit clearly what the function does.

Answer (score 17):

I don't quite understand what you trying to achieve as well but you have few problems with your code:

1. By presence of `@ParameterizedTest` and `@ValueSource` I assume you using JUnit 5. At the same time looks like you marked your method with annotation from JUnit 4 (because only in that case you will get an exception with the text you quoted).
2. `@Test` is redundant when the method is annotated with `@ParametrizedTest`.

You have 2 options how to fix all of the above:

1. If you want to use junit5 then you need to remove `@Test` annotation and make sure that your tests are launched by a runner that supports JUnit 5 ([more info](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit-platform.html)).

   Example:

   ```
   package test;

   import org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTest;
   import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.ValueSource;

   public class TestTest {

       @ParameterizedTest
       @ValueSource(booleans =  {true, false})
       public void test(boolean data) {
           System.out.println(data);
       }
   }
   ```
2. If you want to use JUnit 4 then you need to remove `@ParameterizedTest` and `@ValueSource` annotations and rewrite your test to use parametrized runner ([more info](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Parameterized-tests)).

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove the line **@Test** out of your code